# jquery mobile query string parameters

Tags: forms, jquery-mobile, mobile, query-string

In my application I have back end code as perl and front end development using jquery mobile. When I submit a form on jqm page using the variables x=10 y=20, in the query string instead of replacing the parameters like jqm.com/?x=10&y=20 I get it appended as 
 jqm.com/ id=1000&x=10&y=20. Again I change my values and submit the form I get
 jqm.com/?id=1000&x=10&y=20&id=1000&x=newvalue&y=newvalue

Comment: What's the action of your form?

Answer (score 0):

You have this problem because you haven't specified an `action` attribute in your form. So, by default, it'll send the data to the page itself, thus you have the parameters appended to the current page url every time.

To fix this problem, simply add the `action` attribute like the following example:

```
<form action="a-page-to-send.php" method="post">
  <!-- code goes here -->
</form>
```

Comment: I know I sending it to my self... i do not need to send them to other page.

Comment: Good. In this case, let that your page is called "page.php", just set action="page.php"

Comment: In this case it could depend on other piece of code you haven't posted